# Django POST не удается получить ключ

Tags: python, django

Помогите вытащить из POST запроса ключи. Я из стороннего приложения отправляю запрос в Django и уже далее хочу его обрабатывать, но при попытке извлеч ключи у меня почему то возвращается пустой словарь.
сам запрос отправляю postmen http://127.0.0.1:8000/?email=app@exl.com

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        print(f'Сам запрос который получили {request}')
        print(f'декод запроса {req}')
    return HttpResponse(0)
```

на принтах выводит

Сам запрос который получили <WSGIRequest: POST '/?email=app@exl.com'>
декод запроса

Comment: Что за ключи? `{'email': 'app@exl.com'}`, так?

Comment: да, именно то что мне нужно, а как вы их получили?

Comment: `request.GET`, как в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`HttpRequest.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) — параметры `GET`-запроса
[`HttpRequest.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) — параметры `POST`-запроса

Т.е Вам нужно:

```py
request.GET
request.POST
```